# Syslog with Phalcon on CentOS

Tags: centos, syslog, phalcon

Anyone out there working with Phalcon on CentOS?

I'm trying to use Syslog from [`Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\Syslog`](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/logging.html#syslog-logger) but can't find where can I see the output. AFAIK, CentOS send syslog messages to '/var/log/messages', but I've looked at almost all files in '/var/log' and found nothing.

Currently I'm constructring the Syslog this way:

```
$logger = new SyslogAdapter(null);
```

Is there any setting that I'm missing on Phalcon or my OS?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/ext/logger/adapter/syslog.c#L125 and https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/ext/logger/adapter/syslog.c#L185 it seems that Phalcon proxies all calls to the default [syslog](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php).

I'd sugget to [goggle "centos php syslog"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=centos+php+syslog) and make it work in pure php without Phalcon. It feels this is the keystone to the problem.

**Update**

Just looking over your piece of code, the actual class is called Syslog, not SyslogAdapter, unless you do `use Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\Syslog as SyslogAdapter;`, which I can't tell from the code above :) If syslog via php works, then most likely the issue is with your code. I just tried the below, it works as expected:

```
$logger = new Syslog(null);
$logger->log('test', 'hello world');

// 27/04/2014 19:15:24.922 php[24030]: hello world
```

Comment: Syslog via PHP is working fine. `LOG_INFO` go to `var/log/messages` as expected.

Comment: Updated the answer, check that you're properly importing the class.